# Problem with image in an AlertDialog with the ListView [Android]

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

i have a problem trying to show an image in an AlertDialog with a ListView, here the code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
stringArray = new String[1];

**stringArray[0] = new String(getString( R.string.facebook),getImg( R.drawable.icon ));**

ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);

builder.setTitle("Share");
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
builder.setItems(stringArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

and

```
private Drawable getImg( int res )
        {
            Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable( res );
            img.setBounds( 0, 0, 48, 48 );
            return img;
        }
```

and the error says me: "The constructor String(String,Drawable) is undefined"

I would like, to show an image custom and a text in an AlertDialog with a ListView. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stringArray = new String[1];

**stringArray[0] = new String(getString( R.string.facebook),getImg( R.drawable.icon ));**
```

A `String` is only a `String`. You cannot  put a `Drawable` in the constructur. And as you use the getString method, you dont need the constructor anyway:

```
 stringArray[0] = getString(R.string.facebook);
```

Answer (score 0):

What to you want to achieve with the following line of code?

> stringArray[0] = new String(getString(
>   R.string.facebook),getImg(
>   R.drawable.icon ));

You should change it to

> stringArray[0] = new String(getString(
>   R.string.facebook));